# When using redux-saga, why yield statement is the value of the execution rather than undefined?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, redux, redux-saga

Let's say we have the following generator function:

```
function* testGenerator() {

  const result = yield Promise.resolve('foobar').then(res => res);

  console.log(result);

}
```

If I run this generator with the following line, it logs `undefined`

```
const test = testGenerator();
test.next();
test.next();
```

But in saga, such lines will log `foobar`. I'm just curious what's the mechanism behind this (assigning the result of yield to a variable)

**Edit:**

TL;DR:

[MDN function* reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function*)

> Calling the next() method with an argument will resume the generator
>   function execution, replacing the yield statement where execution was
>   paused with the argument from next()

Basically, to get it to log "foobar", just pass the value of the first yield to the second next so when it resumes, yield statement is replaced by the value:

```
function* testGenerator() {
  const result = yield Promise.resolve('foobar');
  console.log(result);
}

const test = testGenerator();
test.next().value.then(r => test.next(r))
```

Comment: `yield` returns whatever is passed to `next()`. You don't pass anything.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Code review**

First of all, get rid of this; it doesn't do anything

```
const result = yield Promise.resolve('foobar').then(res => res);
```

---

**Your generator works fine**

> If I run this generator with the following line, it logs undefined

No it doesn't. It will log a `{next, value}` each time

```js
function* testGenerator() {
  const result = yield Promise.resolve('foobar');
  console.log(result);
}

let test = testGenerator()

console.log(test.next())
// { value: Promise {[[PromiseStatus]]: "resolved", [[PromiseValue]]: 1}, done: false }

console.log(test.next())
// { value: undefined, done: true }
```

Logging Promises is tricky tho. If you don't believe me, see this

```js
function* testGenerator() {
  const result = yield Promise.resolve('foobar');
  console.log(result);
}

let test = testGenerator()

test.next().value.then(console.log)
// "foobar"
```

---

**Coroutines**

> But in saga, such lines will log foobar. I'm just curious what's the mechanism behind this (assigning the result of yield to a variable)

Redux Saga is built to step thru a generator and process the various effects. A Promise is just one of the many things you could yield.

Here's an example of a simple coroutine function that takes a generator instance and expects Promises to be yielded until the last result. Notice the 2-way flow of data.

- `yield` sends data out of the generator
- `gen.next(x)` sends the next value into the generator

So we're exploiting this ability of generators to send a promise *out*, and send the Promise's *resolved* value back *in*, which allows the resolved Promise's value to be assigned directly to a variable

```js
const coro = gen => {
  const next = x => {
    const {value, done} = gen.next(x)
    if (done)
      return value
    else
      return value.then(next)
  }
  return next()
}

function* testGenerator () {
  const x = yield Promise.resolve(1)
  console.log(x) // 1

  const y = yield Promise.resolve(2)
  console.log(y) // 2

  const z = yield Promise.resolve(3)
  console.log(z) // 3

  return x + y + z
}

coro(testGenerator()).then(console.log)
// "6"
```

---

**`async` & `await`**

And now that you understand that, you understand *exactly* how the proposed `async`/`await` work – functionality of this next snippet may vary depending on your browser's support.

Changes:

- we no longer need a `coro` helper
- use `async` keyword instead of a generator `function*`
- use `await` keyword instead of `yield`

Behaviour is the same.

- use `await` to send a Promise out
- Promise's resolved value is sent back in as return value of `await` call
- `async` functions implicitly return a Promise, so chain a `.then` call to get the final value out

```js
const testRoutine = async () => {
  const x = await Promise.resolve(1)
  console.log(x) // 1

  const y = await Promise.resolve(2)
  console.log(y) // 2

  const z = await Promise.resolve(3)
  console.log(z) // 3

  return x + y + z
}

testRoutine().then(console.log)
// "6"
```

---

**Homegrown coroutines**

You shouldn't be rolling your own coroutines because there's a lot of stuff to watch out for. For example, if the generator `throw`s an Error or `yield`s a rejected Promise, the implementation above would just swallow it.

For **demonstration purposes** I'll show you how to nail it down a little bit more, but if you're interested in covering all of your bases, you should read the Redux Saga source code, or the source code of another coroutine library like [tj/co](https://github.com/tj/co)

```js
const coro = gen => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const next = x => {
      try {
        let {value, done} = gen.next(x)
        return done ? resolve(value) : value.then(next, reject)
      }
      catch (err) {
        reject(err)
      }
    }
    next()
  })
}

function* noYield() { return 5 }

function* throwsUp() { throw Error("OOPS") }

function* yieldReject() { yield Promise.reject('NO') }

function* normal() { let x = yield Promise.resolve(16); return x * x; }

coro(noYield())
  .then(console.log, console.error) // 5

coro(throwsUp())
  .then(console.log, console.error) // [Error: OOPS]
  
coro(yieldReject())
  .then(console.log, console.error) // "NO"
  
coro(normal())
  .then(console.log, console.error) // 256
```

Comment: _"it logs undefined ... No it doesn't."_ It does. Run the code.

Comment: Great thanks. Besides `{next, value}` you first snippet also logged `undefined` actually, and that's what I meant in the question (why the result of yield is different, how it's replaced). **gen.next(x) sends the next value into the generator**. This demystifies it, thanks. I should have read the basics of generator function more carefully. And thanks for the thorough elaboration around it.